# Is it possible to map stored procedures to entities in EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, relational-database

Something like this in EF Core

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                    .MapToStoredProcedures();
}
```

EF 6 has this functionality that will auto create stored procedures. I hope there is something similar to EF Core or a work around to achieve code-first approach.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/245

Comment: Thanks for this but I can't seem to find a solution here on my problem. Though I understand that EF Core still doesn't have this feature. That is why I am hoping to see solutions on how to implement this despite the limitation.

Comment: Sorry I'm not aware of any third party implementations.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is something which it can help u.
u can create ur own stored procedures with T-SQL commands. if u wanna try that way,u need to enable migrations and create one.
after u have one,u need to create a partial class which is inherits ur DbMigration

```
public partial class SPAdder : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateStoredProcedure(
            "dbo.ExampleSP",
            CreateStoredProcedure(
 "dbo.ExampleSP",
 p => new
 {
     Name = p.String(),
     LastName = p.String(),
     Hometowm = p.String(),
     StudentID = p.Int(),
 },
 body:
     @"
      if(exists(Select * from Student where StudentID = @StudentID))
          begin
              Update Student Set Name = @Name, LastName = @LastName, Hometown = @Hometown where StudentID =     @StudentID
          end
      else
          begin
              Insert Students(Name, LastName, Hometown) Values(@Name, @LastName, @Hometown)"
          end    
        );
         
    }
     
    public override void Down()
    {
        DropStoredProcedure("dbo.ExampleSP");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but how do I execute this?

Comment: after u create ur own stored procedure,u can test ur codes in ur main class. `using (EntitiesContext  context = new EntitiesContext())  
    {  
        EmployeeMaster employee = new EmployeeMaster();  
        employee.Code = "A0001";  
        employee.Name = "Jignesh Trivedi";  
        employee.DepartmentId = 1;  
        context.Employees.Add(employee);  
        context.SaveChanges();  
        Console.ReadLine();  
    }   `  after u wrote this,do not forgot to dispose ur log so u can check it out more clearly

Comment: How will this Stored Procedure get automatically binded to the Add on Entity?